# Necking stage in bubble detachment

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, surface-tension, navier-stokes, bubbles

The first image is the bubble dynamics in nucleate boiling, in a) you can see that the bubble is detaching by minimizing contact line with surface until zero, while in b) the bubble is enlongate and forming a neck where the detachment happen. It clearly that the hydrophobicity of 2 surfaces affect the detachment mechanism. But why is this the case?

And how is enlongate and necking process happen? these two stages of detachment are common see such as dripping faucet, bubble pinch-off from nozzle (pic 2),etc. Can you explain it by force analysis model?

Thank you!

[image: Boiling bubble]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean bubble or do you mean drop?

Comment: @ChetMiller I mean bubble as my title, but the same pattern can be observed with the drop in the air.